# Until when travel the particles after the Big Bang with light speed?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, big-bang

When I think of an explosion it lasts a fraction of second. When the entire mass of the universe explodes, how much time passes before the perfect sphere slows down, from traveling at/near the speed of light from the forming of atoms? Or is the big bang still happening, but we are inside the sphere, while the shock wave still moves through space?

Comment: It's not an explosion and the mass was never concentrated in one spot.

Comment: @CuriousOne fixed?

Comment: Just as bad as before.

Comment: See [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/50583). There is no sphere, and there is no explosion.

Comment: Also, note that the work "quarks" appears in the title but is not referenced anywhere in the body.

Comment: The answer to your first question can be answered regardless of your misunderstanding of Big Bang. The time passing before atoms begin to form is [379,000 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_%28cosmology%29), which is the time it took for the temperature to drop sufficiently for atoms not to be constantly ionized.

Comment: I think that the question is equivalent to _"Is the BB still in progress ? Considering the timelines of the BB, what let us say that it had ended at some moment ? I suspect the expansion to be a remnant of the Guth inflation"_ . title : _"Is the BB still in progress ?"_ . It remains to translate it in correct english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer to your first question can be answered regardless of your misunderstanding of Big Bang. The time passing before atoms begin to form is [379,000 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_%28cosmology%29), which is the time it took for the temperature to drop sufficiently for atoms not to be constantly ionized.
>
> – [pela](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/70207/pela), in a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232759/big-bang-quarks-travelling-at-light-speed/232854#comment507311_232759).

Comment: There are at least two problems with what you've done here. First, from a strict point of view you are in violation of the license agreement here. You haven't said where you got this nor from whom in a way that satisfies the license. Second it represents and attempt gain by simply coping another users contribution which is gauche to say the least.

Comment: @dmckee I'm am so tired of people using the comment box to answer. When someone answers in this way it is only fair that it gets adopted..I will refrain and delete if necessary.

Comment: @dmckee the source is right at the end, "pela"

Comment: @MitchellPorter Thus *"from a strict point of view"* and *"in a way that satisfies the license"* which is a surprisingly high hurdle leading to the [recent consideration of adopting a different license for code snippets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) (see also several following threads on the mother meta. What Jen has done is casual and more or less works as long as (a) the comment above is left and (b) this content isn't copied elsewhere. But neither of those things is guaranteed.

Comment: @Jen I have re-formatted your post to comply with the license and our plagiarism guidelines. The licence requires the links to the post source and the user, but the more important part (which is more likely to be the source of the downvotes) is the plagiarism bit: you need to make it visually clear that you are quoting someone else. I feel you on the answers in comments, but we generally frown upon re-quotes like this unless you've prompted the user in the comments to re-post as an answer, and they've declined. And if you're doing this, don't strip links!